# I have to search from MySQL Db table with multiple parameters in where clause using POST method(Restfull) in Spring boot?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

MySQL DB Table :

[image]

Classes are as follows: The issue is how to handle the object in crud repository as there is no such existing function there. So how to override an existing one.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/find", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public User getUser(@RequestBody  UserFormDto userForm) {
    Holder h = new Holder();
    h.setName(userForm.getName());
    h.setEmail(userForm.getEmail());
    return userRepository.findOne(h);//holder);

}


package hello;
public class Holder {   
private String name;
private String email;

public class Holder {   
private String name;
private String email;

public Holder(){

}
public Holder(String name, String email) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}}
```

---

UserFormDto to pass data to Holder.

```
package hello;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern; 
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;


public class UserFormDto {
private String name;
private String email;

public UserFormDto(String name, String email) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
}

public UserFormDto() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}}



  package hello;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
//  User findOne(Holder h);}
```

---

Now How should I work with crudRepository? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Table attributes are as follows: id, name, email and I want to search on the basis of id and name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Data supports automatic query building based on the method name in `CrudRepository` (see [Query Creation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation) )

Add a `findByIdAndEmail` method to it , and it should work (note that I don't see the point of searching on the id plus another field at the same time, except if your id is not the PK ):

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

    List<User> findByIdAndEmail(Long id, String email);

}
```